# How to Collect Month wise school fee where months are selected from checkboxes?

Tags: mysql, database, procedure

I am new in this  field, I am working on a school fee management system, fee collected from students on month basis, yearly basis etc

My MySQL database schema is as follow

**academic_classes** table

class_id                    class_name
  1                                     1st

2                                    2nd

.....and so on

**Fee_types** Table

```
fee_type_id            fee_name
     1                     Admission Fee

     2                     Tuition Fee

     3                     Sports Fee
```

**class_wise_fee_plan**  table

plan_id    class_id       fee_id         amount
     1                1                  1                5000

```
 2                1                  2                 1150

 3                 1                 3                    350
```

fee amount is according to classes
according to your suggestion I have add a new table 
for fee frequency yearly, monthly  etc

**fee_writeoff**  table

fee_writeoff_id      fee_id          months
        1                         1                    apr

```
    2                         2                    jan

    3                         2                    feb
```

and so on ...

I have 12 checkboxes for **months** in front end, How to calculate or show together fee values and fee name based on check boxes.

I want this type of Results

FeeName                    Apr       May       Jun   ..... Total

Admission fee           5000       0            0               5000

Tution Fee                  1100      1100     1100         3300

Total                            6100      1100     1100         8300

how to create mysql stored procedure if months name selected from checkboxes from front end because months name are comma saparated how to loop through and create cases

Answer (score 1):

Try below query using CASE, it is not a complete solution as you have asked for but this will solve some of your issues.

```
SELECT ft.fee_name, (CASE WHEN apr=1 THEN fee_amount ELSE 0 END) AS apr,
(CASE WHEN may=1 THEN fee_amount ELSE 0 END) AS apr,
(CASE WHEN jun=1 THEN fee_amount ELSE 0 END) AS apr,
(CASE WHEN jul=1 THEN fee_amount ELSE 0 END) AS apr,
(CASE WHEN aug=1 THEN fee_amount ELSE 0 END) AS apr,
(CASE WHEN apr=1 THEN fee_amount ELSE 0 END) AS apr,
FROM fee_type ft INNER JOIN fee_plan fp
USING (fee_id)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
fee_name           APR    MAY    JUNE     JULY     AUG

Admission Fee      5000    0        0        0       0

Tuition Fee        1150   1150   1150     1150     1150
```

Comment: @Rammehar: Was this any helpful ?

Comment: it is helpful for me thanking u very much  Rockse Sir

Comment: kindly accept the answer if you think it is the solution to your problem

Comment: sir may you plz tell me how to build case in while loop in mysql stored procedure because months are comma sparated in a variable ?

Comment: may u plz tell me how to show this result out put into html table using php loop or etc

Answer (score 0):

First I've to note that to design a schema you should understand the basics of relational model. When you put your spreadsheet layout to a relational table you won't get it right.

So I redesigned you schema in a relational matter. It's not the only possible schema, though it depends on rest of your application.

*Schema*

```
CREATE TABLE `fee` (
  `fee_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fee_id`) 
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `fee_writeoff` (
  `fee_writeoff_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fee_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `date` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fee_writeoff_id`),
  INDEX `fee_id`(`fee_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fee_writeoff_has_fee`
    FOREIGN KEY (`fee_id`)
    REFERENCES `fee` (`fee_id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `fee_plan` (
  `fee_plan_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fee_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `amount` DECIMAL(10,0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fee_plan_id`),
  INDEX `fee_id`(`fee_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fee_plan_has_fee`
    FOREIGN KEY (`fee_id`)
    REFERENCES `fee` (`fee_id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE  
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

*Data*

```
INSERT INTO `fee`(`fee_id`, `name`) VALUES
  (1, 'Admission Fee'),
  (2, 'Tuition Fee');

INSERT INTO `fee_writeoff`(`fee_id`, `date`) VALUES
  (1, '2000-04-01'),
  (2, '2000-01-01'),
  (2, '2000-02-01'),
  (2, '2000-03-01'),
  (2, '2000-04-01'),
  (2, '2000-05-01'),
  (2, '2000-06-01'),
  (2, '2000-07-01'),
  (2, '2000-08-01'),
  (2, '2000-09-01'),
  (2, '2000-10-01'),
  (2, '2000-11-01'),
  (2, '2000-12-01');

INSERT INTO `fee_plan`(`fee_id`, `amount`) VALUES
  (1, 5000),
  (2, 1150);
```

*Query*

```
SELECT 
  name,
  SUM(CASE MONTH(`date`) WHEN  4 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `April`,
  SUM(CASE MONTH(`date`) WHEN  5 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `May`,
  SUM(CASE MONTH(`date`) WHEN  6 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `June`,
  SUM(CASE MONTH(`date`) WHEN  7 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `July`,
  SUM(CASE MONTH(`date`) WHEN  8 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `August`,
  SUM(CASE MONTH(`date`) WHEN  9 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `September`,
  SUM(CASE MONTH(`date`) WHEN 10 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `October`,
  SUM(CASE MONTH(`date`) WHEN 11 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `November`,
  SUM(CASE MONTH(`date`) WHEN 12 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `December`,
  SUM(CASE MONTH(`date`) WHEN  1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `January`,
  SUM(CASE MONTH(`date`) WHEN  2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `February`,
  SUM(CASE MONTH(`date`) WHEN  3 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `March`,
  SUM(amount) AS `Total`
FROM fee
JOIN fee_writeoff USING(fee_id)
JOIN fee_plan USING(fee_id)
GROUP BY name WITH ROLLUP
```

Here is [the SQLFiddle snippet](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40438/11).

Comment: Sir, sorry to disturb u again I have a table named as academic_classes fields are class_id, class_name and another table is fee_types fields are fee_type_id, fee_name, fee_frequency frequency means yearly monthly quertly etc, and a last table is class_wise_fee_plan fields are fee_plan_id, fee_type_id, class_id, fee_amount please help me to create class wise fee structure for each class fee collection from student based on monthly, yearly I am very thankful to you sir please help to create proper schema

Comment: @RammeharSharma Add a section to your question with the request, additional tables and their fields. I'll take a look. It's barely readable as a comment.

Comment: Sir I dont know how to add section? can u plz tell me

Comment: sir how to build case in while loop in stored procedure because months names are in checkboxes and stored in a variable as comma saparated

Comment: @RammeharSharma I'm asking you to edit your question and add a list of tables you have now. Generally people make bold "UPDATE:" in the end of current text and then insert a clarification part to the question. I see it in the scope of the question.

Comment: @RammeharSharma But considering the stored procedure comment I have to say it violates StackOverflow flow. It's not a generic forum. You need to ask separate questions on separate posts, not asking it in comments. Though, I can only suggest not to implement your business logic in a database, it's really a design mistake. Do it in application layer, and read [the classical article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10746/Dude-where-s-my-business-logic) for rationale.

Comment: Saaj Sir please give me some guidence ?

Comment: may u plz tell me how to loop through dynamic months name in html table using php